# Parsing unicode in unescaped XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, unicode

I'm trying to parse some poorly formatted XML.

I say poorly formatted - because everyone knows that you're not supposed to have un-escaped ampersands in an XML file.

Problem is, I need to collect some **unicode formatted phrases** from an XML file. I need the format to be as close to the original as possible. You can replicate this issue in your console log...

```
console.log($("<test>&#xE2;</test>").text())
// Outputs 'â' instead of desired '&#xE2;'
```

I've tried every combination of `escape`, `unescape()`, `encodeURI()`, `decodeURI()` I can fathom.

I've tried both settings for jQuery's `ajax({processData: bool})` flag. All answers I've found point to these solutions - and it seems like none of them work...

How can I modify the above code to output the original XML content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: It isn't. This isn't a generic escape/unescape question - it's specific to unicode. If you're gonna flag, at least READ the question. Thanks.

Comment: I READ the question. Just missunderstood it. Next time try to explain your problem in a propper way with some xml sample code and javascript code that explains how you try to read out the phrases. Your title is missleading: You don't want to `parse` it. You want to retrieve it from the xml without the automatic exchange with the unicode character. That's something different.

Comment: in your sample it would work to replace all `&` with `&amp;`. You don't need the overhead of creating HTMLNodes: `console.log($('<test>'+'&#xE2;'.replace('&', '&amp;')+'</test>').text())` [Here is a little fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/wyz9yfko/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new Option(yourUnescapedXml).innerHTML`. So to answer your question directly,

```
console.log($(`<test>${new Option('&#xE2;').innerHTML}</test>`).text())
```

This creates an [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement), then immediately gets its (escaped) innerHtml.

Comment: No idea how that works - but I can't argue with the results! Thanks man! (edit: Need to wait 6 more minutes before accepting answer - but I'm choosing this if anyone else posts. It's the most direct answer)

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain how it works. If you want to accept this answer, please mark it as such.

Comment: Done. Thanks again - and for the additional info. Would have marked it sooner but there is a 10 minute cooldown from asking a question and selecting an answer.